# Exploit circulating Facebook with a .pnh file embedded in a <img> tag

Tags: exploit, html, facebook

Not sure how long this link will be up, but this is the page where users get redirected after trying to read a fake news post in someone timeline.

**[WARNING: ACCESS IN A CONTROLLED ENVIRONMENT]**

```
http://yt-news.info/s/?id=qlktvqt46220jr8q6
```

Here's the link bait as a news on facebook `https://facebook.com/290091591171980`

What's happening? .pnh files seems to be related with Adobe. And in this case it seems like a visit counter. Not sure if it offers any harm. However, following the the url facebook offers did triggers some anti-virus softwares.

Is this a XSS attack? Or just a simple redirect with this unknown .pnh?

**EDIT:**

> This extension interfaces with http://whos.amung.us. If you use their
>   widget on your website, the extension gets how many users are on your
>   website and puts the count in your status bar. To configure this after
>   it has been installed, open up the addons list from the Firefox menu,
>   click on this addon, click options, and enter your 8-12 character key
>   which is found in the html you were given. Ie: the image name, without
>   the '.png' part, it's pretty self explanatory. Close options, and soon
>   thereafter your user count will be updated in real time :)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/whosamungus-users-online-count/

It seems like it's a phishing attempt:

http://viewtubes.info/bebadas/chrome.html

Comment: The yt-news.info site seems to not work any more. 

See: `130 ;( eric@crunchbang ~ $ wget http://yt-news.info/s/?id=qlktvqt46220jr8q6
--2014-07-06 00:13:33--  http://yt-news.info/s/?id=qlktvqt46220jr8q6
Resolving yt-news.info (yt-news.info)... 37.0.123.217
Connecting to yt-news.info (yt-news.info)|37.0.123.217|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.`

Comment: @eric_lagergren The redirection changes depending on the brownser. That's the reason you can't download it. Be sure to access the full url too.

Comment: Anyway, I think that's a script kiddie...

Comment: It times out in both Chrome and Firefox. The Facebook link prompts me to download an `.html` file that contains a JS redirection to the `http://yt-news.info...` website.

Comment: @eric_lagergren Not sure maybe there's a block by IP location. Here's up (Brazil). The download on facebook it's meant to people to download and open in their browsers.